# What's the probability that my pants wear out today.

Tags: probability, expectation

I want to create a model for how pants are worn out.

I know that the expected life span of my pants is `n` days.

I don't know how old the pants are, and I don't have any way of measuring how worn they are. I am assuming that my pants will go from completely serviceable to completely worn out in a single day.

So, given only that the expected life span of my pants is `n` days, how do I figure out the probability that my pants will ware out on a given day?

Comment: If you have some important meeting that day, the probability is $1$.

Comment: Isn't it just 1/n? Am i missing something here?

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume that the pants are not "ageing" ?

Comment: @Peter Yes, that is a reasonable assumption. You might say that we assume immortal pants in that the chance of their death does not change as they age.

Comment: Such a distribution should be well known.

Comment: @Peter Yeah, I would have thought so too, but the answer isn't obvious to me, and googling the question hasn't yield anything.

Comment: @DavidL is right, this was a simple question and I shouldn't have posted it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you are assuming, the probability distribution should be "memoryless"; and according to wikipedia,

> The only memoryless continuous probability distributions are the
>   [exponential distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).

So you can obtain the desired probability using an exponential distribution with average $n$.

Comment: Actually, because the way the question is posed implies *discrete* support (since we are interested in the distribution of the number of days until the pants wear out), we should be considering a **geometric** distribution.

Comment: If you assume that, the most likely day is the first day.